# Make Reference to Variable in a View in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am to make modifications to a view in SQL Server. Below is the view code:

```
ALTER View [dbo].[SupplierPOImport_Errors] 
AS
SELECT 
SupplierName, 
Case SupplierID WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'SupplierFound',
PONumber,
InvoiceNumber,
InvoiceDate,
ItemNumber,
ItemBarcode,
Description,
Quantity,
Cost, 
Tax,
Case ItemID WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'ItemFound',
Case PurchaseOrderID WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'POFound',
--Case Quantity WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'UnderSupplied',
(SELECT SUM(quantity * Cost) FROM SupplierPOImport) AS TotalExGST,
(SELECT SUM(quantity * Cost * (100 + Tax)/100) FROM SupplierPOImport) AS TotalIncGST,


  -- REQ 5
  Case WHEN ItemNumber = (SELECT OrderNumber
  FROM [RMS_SO_SM_PO].[dbo].[PurchaseOrderEntry]
  INNER JOIN
  [RMS_SO_SM_PO].[dbo].[PurchaseOrder]
  ON PurchaseOrder.ID = PurchaseOrderEntry.PurchaseOrderID
  WHERE 
  PurchaseOrder.PONumber = SupplierPOImport.PONumber AND
  PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber = SupplierPOImport.ItemNumber) THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END as 'POAdded',

-- REQ 6 A

  CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ItemNumber FROM SupplierPOImport t1 
   INNER JOIN SupplierList t2 ON t1.ItemNumber = t2.ReorderNumber
   INNER JOIN ITEM t3 ON t2.ItemID = t3.ID
   INNER JOIN SupplierPOImport_Errors t ON t.ItemNumber = t1.ItemNumber 
   WHERE 
    t3.SupplierID = t1.SupplierID AND
    t1.ItemNumber = t2.ReorderNumber AND
    t1.ItemNumber = t.ItemNumber)   
    THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS 'PRIMARY'
FROM SupplierPOImport

GO
```

REQ 6 returns more than one record, because the ItemNumber for `ItemNumber = SupplierList.ReorderNumber` refers to the table `SupplierPOImport`. I need it to refer to the ItemNumber in the view, as this is talking to a VB.NET application, that imports the data into the table SupplierPOImport. With the View, I am able to write logic for every row in the datagrid in the application.

So, what I would like is a way to compare my Query, against the ItemNumber Value in my View. The way REQ 5 works is that for every row that is imported, it sends back a YES or NO to the VB.NET Application. It checks whether the current ItemNumber is equal to what the query returns. The query has a PONumber WHERE clause(it gets it from the View). However for REQ 6, I want a way to refer to the ItemNumber.

Essentially, I want it to return YES whenever my ItemNumber exists in the query. I have tried to use TempItemNum = SupplierList.ReorderNumber but SQL does not recognize TempItemNumb in the query.

I get this error below when I try to execute this:

View or function 'SupplierPOImport_Errors' contains a self-reference. Views or functions cannot reference themselves directly or indirectly.

Could not use view or function 'SupplierPOImport_Errors' because of binding errors.

Comment: This isn't very clear. We don't have the full view, and some sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: Please post the entire view.  If it's too big to fit in a single question, then _you_ need to find a minimal version to show us.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the entire view that I am using. Is this helpful now?

Comment: I'm still scratching my head at _ItemNumber in the view_. What does this mean? What bearing does it have on the application?

Comment: It holds the different ItemNumbers for each row of the table, so it does its calculations and passes it to the application for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question returns a YES or NO in a column but the function you posed as an answer returns an ItemNumber. So here's a guess of what you want.

The SQL you posted was actually really close to what was required. Please try this and if it isn't what you want, please explain why it is different.

I have only done one column here. If this is progress we can work on the next column.

```
ALTER View [dbo].[SupplierPOImport_Errors] 
AS
SELECT 
SupplierName, 
Case SupplierID WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'SupplierFound',
PONumber,
InvoiceNumber,
InvoiceDate,
ItemNumber,
ItemBarcode,
Description,
Quantity,
Cost, 
Tax,
Case ItemID WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'ItemFound',
Case PurchaseOrderID WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'POFound',
--Case Quantity WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS 'UnderSupplied',
(SELECT SUM(quantity * Cost) FROM SupplierPOImport) AS TotalExGST,
(SELECT SUM(quantity * Cost * (100 + Tax)/100) FROM SupplierPOImport) AS TotalIncGST,

  CASE WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM [dbo].[PurchaseOrderEntry]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[PurchaseOrder]
  ON PurchaseOrder.ID = PurchaseOrderEntry.PurchaseOrderID
  WHERE 
  PurchaseOrder.PONumber = I.PONumber AND
  PurchaseOrderEntry.OrderNumber = I.ItemNumber
  ) THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END as 'POAdded'


FROM SupplierPOImport I
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear at all. I should be more articulate in my questions. What I have done is this in the View:

  -- REQ 6
  CASE WHEN ItemNumber = (SELECT dbo.MCS_CheckPrimarySupplier(ItemNumber)) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS 'PRIMARY', 

So, This function only returns a value that should be equal to the current ItemNumber in the view... does this make sense? I am not an SQL guy, Mostly I develop for NAV, so SQL is new territory

Comment: notice how when I call a function and pass in the ItemNumber, I can use that in my query(refer to the function I showed), but when I write the same query in the view, I cannot refer to that ItemNumber that I am passing now instead... Does this make things clear?...

Comment: Did the view return the correct result or not? If not, why?

Comment: In my answer, it does exactly the same thing, except that you are not using an expensive function.

Comment: “The current item in the view” is just “SupplierPOImport.ItemNumber”

Comment: I see. I will accept this as the answer, as this works great. Cant believe how simple it was. Thanks.

Comment: Great. The learning to take from this is, in SQL, try to think _set based_, not _procedural_

Answer (score 0):

In Req 6 you do an INNER JOIN against

```
SupplierPOImport_Errors
```

which is the same name you try to use for the view you try to create. That’s the problem. I guess you already have a table with the same name. If that’s the case, just use a different name for the view you are creating. Prefixing tables with T_ and views with V_ is a useful naming convention to avoid that

Comment: Table is named SupplierPOImport, View is named SupplierPOImport_Errors, The way I wrote Req 5, I am able to do what I want, but thats not working for Req 6.

Comment: Please take another look at line 4 of Req 6